# ng-repeat not updating when new data is introduced

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a simple app where it takes data from a local json object and displays it on the screen. this part works perfectly, there is also a feature where you can fill out a form to add a new element to the json and it will also display on the page however this is not working.

I can tell the function that is supposed to push the data to the JSON is working because its secondary function is to clear the form data after submission which it is doing.. I also logged the JSON after the ng-click submit button is clicked and I can see the new data added in the log entry but ng-repeat is not adding it to the page.

heres the code
index.html

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AngTest </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">


            <!-- nav bar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Star Wars BnB</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
            <!-- Min / Max Price Filter -->
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="price-form">
                <div class="row price-form-row" ng-if="!addListing">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Min Price</span>
                        <select name="minPrice" id="minPrice" ng-model="priceInfo.min" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">$0</option>
                            <option value="500">$500</option>
                            <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                            <option value="10000">$10,000</option>
                            <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                            <option value="1000000000000">$1,000,000,000,000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Max Price</span>
                        <select name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" ng-model="priceInfo.max" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">$0</option>
                            <option value="500">$500</option>
                            <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                            <option value="10000">$10,000</option>
                            <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                            <option value="1000000000000">$1,000,000,000,000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <button
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-click="addListing = !addListing"
                    ng-show="!addListing"> Add Listing
                </button>

                <button
                    class="btn btn-danger"
                    ng-click="addListing = !addListing"
                    ng-show="addListing"> Close
                </button>

                <div class="listing-form" ng-if="addListing">
                    <h4>Add a Listing</h4>
                    <div class="row listing-form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Name"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="newListing.name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Price</span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Price"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="newListing.price">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Address</span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Enter a address"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="newListing.address">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
                                <textarea
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Enter a description"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="newListing.description">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Allegiance</span>
                                <select 
                                    type="select" 
                                    name="propertyType" 
                                    id="propertyType" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    ng-model="newListing.details.allegiance">
                                        <option value="Empire">Empire</option>
                                        <option value="Rebels">Rebels</option>
                                        <option value="Neutral">Neutral</option>  
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Leader</span>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Leader Name"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="newListing.details.leader">
                                </input>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary listing-button" ng-click="addCrib(newListing)" ng-show="addListing">Add </button>
                    <pre> {{newListing | json}} </pre>
                </div>             
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="container">
                <p id="desclaimer">(note: all prices are in Galactic Credits although some (Jabba) may accept barter)</p>
                <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="crib in cribs | cribsFilter:priceInfo"> <!--pass in priceInfor arg into cribsFilter(listing argument is assigned to the crib in crib as the first argument in a filter is always the current ng-repeat obj) -->
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="thumbPic" ng-src="{{crib.image}}.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div ng-hide="showDetails === true">
                                <h3>{{crib.name}}</h3>
                                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><strong>Address: </strong>{{crib.address}}</p>
                                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i><strong>Price: </strong>{{crib.price | currency}}</p>
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-hide="showDetails === true" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
                                Details
                            </button>

                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-show="showDetails === true" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
                                Details
                            </button>

                            <div class="deatils" ng-show="showDetails === true" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
                                <h4>
                                    <span class="">Allegiance: <p>{{crib.details.allegiance}}</p></span><br>
                                    <span class="">Leader: <p>{{crib.details.leader}}</p></span>
                                </h4>
                                <p><strong>Description: </strong>{{crib.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    </body>
    <footer>
        <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script stc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/CribsController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/cribsFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters/cribsFilter.js"></script>
</html>
<!-- http://localhost:8888/AngTest/ -->
```

Controller

```
app.controller('cribsController', ['$scope','cribsFactory', function($scope, cribsFactory) {
    $scope.$watch.cribs=[];

    $scope.priceInfo = { // set default date for priceInfo so that page is not blank on load
        min: 0,
        max: 1000000000000
    }





     $scope.addCrib = function(newListing) {
      if(newListing) {
        newListing.image = "img/swdefault";  //set default listing image
        $scope.cribs.push(newListing); //push data into new listing
        $scope.newListing = {}; // clear newlisting field 
        console.log($scope.cribs);
      }
    };
    cribsFactory.success(function(data){
        $scope.cribs = data;
    });  
}]);
```

here is a link to the git hub: https://github.com/ericbezanson/StarWarsBnB
and the github pages to see the issue: https://ericbezanson.github.io/StarWarsBnB/

any help would be GREATLY appreciated. thanks!

Comment: have you tried $scope.$apply() after the push?

Comment: Use   $scope.$apply();

Comment: It adds the listing for me.

Comment: Hmm I tried to add $scope.$apply() after the push and it is saying apply is not defined.